# What is this code? And why is it working? C++

Tags: c++

I know  almost everything in this code except the last line. What is he doing after cout? And what is it called? My code for the same problem is almost thrice as big. And I was really shocked after I saw this. I'm new to c++ and it is my first time seeing something like this. I didn't even know that you can use parentheses as he did in his code. It would be nice if you answer noob friendly.
Thank you

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    string c[]={"","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};
    cin>>a>>b;
    for(int i=a;i<=b;i++)
        cout<<((i<=9)?c[i]:((i%2==0)?"even":"odd"))<<endl;
}
```

Now my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Complete the code.
    int a;
int b;
cin >> a >> b;

for ( int n = a; n <= b; n++) {
     if ( n >= 1 && n <= 9 ) {

    string num;

    switch(n) {
    case 1: 
    num = "one";
    break;
    case 2: 
    num = "two";
    break;
    case 3: 
    num = "three";
    break;
    case 4: 
    num = "four";
    break;
    case 5: 
    num = "five";
    break;
    case 6: 
    num = "six";
    break;
    case 7: 
    num = "seven";
    break;
    case 8: 
    num = "eight";
    break;
    case 9: 
    num = "nine";
    break;
}
  cout << num << "\n" ;


    } else if (n > 9 && n % 2 == 0) {
    cout << "even \n" ; 
    } else {
    cout <<  "odd \n" ; }

}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `expr ? x : y` is a ternary statement. What you show in the first example is a nested ternary statement. As far as use of parentheses go, that's not out of the ordinary. Might be a touch excessive, but it's nothing crazy. Your code doesn't need `<cstdio>` at all.

Comment: You should get into the habit of indenting your code properly.  A jumbled mess like this is hard to read and leads to mistakes.

Comment: Note that using `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std` are both really bad habits to get into. Try and avoid this. Be clear about what your dependencies are and where the components live. `string` might be something of your own construction, or that abomination from `cs50.h`, but `std::string` is universally understood.

Answer (score 3):

The original code can be made more understandable by breaking it up. First the includes:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
```

Then define the number constants:

```
const std::string number[] ={"zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};
```

Then define a function that does what that ugly nested ternary does:

```
std::string nameOf(int v) {
  if (v < 10) {
    return number[v];
  }

  if (v % 2 == 0) {
    return "even";
  }

  return "odd";
}
```

Then the final code is actually really simple:

```
int main()
{
  int a,b;
  std::cin >> a >> b;

  for(int i=a; i<=b; ++i) {
    std::cout << nameOf(i) << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

A ternary (`X ? Y : Z`) tests if expression `X` evaluates to a truthful value, and if it does then evaluates and returns expression `Y`. If not, expression `Z` is evaluated and returned.

This is different from a regular `if` which has no return value, but otherwise works the same way.

From a readability standpoint you want to keep your use of ternary operators to a minimum, they can get really confusing. Using a nested ternary is really uncalled for.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [ternary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c-cplusplus-ternary-operator#:~:text=This%20operator%20returns%20one%20of,returned%20as%20a%20final%20result.) operator.

Comment: Also known as a ["conditional operator"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator).

Answer (score 0):

`?:` is a ternary [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator):

> The conditional operator expressions have the form
>
> `E1 ? E2 : E3`
>
> The first operand of the conditional operator is evaluated and contextually converted to `bool`. After both the value evaluation and all side effects of the first operand are completed, if the result was `true`, the second operand is evaluated. If the result was `false`, the third operand is evaluated.

So, in your example, this statement:

```
cout<<((i<=9)?c[i]:((i%2==0)?"even":"odd"))<<endl;
```

Has 2 nested `?:` operators being used:

- in the first one:

  `E1` is `(i<=9)`
  `E2` is `c[i]`
  `E3` is `((i%2==0)?"even":"odd")`
- in the second one, from `E3` above:

  `E1` is `(i%2==0)`
  `E2` is `"even"`
  `E3` is `"odd"`

That statement is *equivalent* to this:

```
std::string temp; // because c[i] is a std::string...
if (i <= 9) {
    temp = c[i];
} else {
    if ((i % 2) == 0) {
        temp = "even";
    } else {
        temp = "odd";
    }
}
cout << temp << endl;
```